# How to fix kcmshell5 error: Could not find module bluedevildevices (bluedevil is installed!)

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth

I do not have the bluetooth icon in system settings or my system tray in Kubuntu 15.04, so I tried launching it manually with `bluedevil-monolithic`. But  the "configure Bluetooth" menu option from the resulting system tray icon fails with the following errors - how can I fix them?

```
Could not find module 'bluedevildevices'. See kcmshell5 --list for the full list of modules.
Could not find module 'bluedeviltransfer'. See kcmshell5 --list for the full list of modules.
Could not find module 'bluedeviladapters'. See kcmshell5 --list for the full list of modules.
```

More info:

- `bluedevil` is installed (version *2.0~rc1really1.3.2-0ubuntu1*)
- `/usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n` and `bluedevil-monolithic` are running (and no other bluetooth-related software containing "bt" or "blue" is running)
- the output from `blutooth` is `bluetooth = on` (after `rfkill unblock bluetooth`)

Installed packages with "blue" in their name:

```
$ aptitude search blue | grep '^i'
i   bluedevil                       - KDE Bluetooth stack                       
i   bluez                           - Bluetooth tools and daemons               
i   bluez-alsa                      - Bluetooth ALSA support                    
i   bluez-compat                    - BlueZ 3.x compatibility binaries          
i   bluez-cups                      - Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS         
i   bluez-dbg                       - Bluetooth tools and daemons (with debuggin
i A bluez-gstreamer                 - Bluetooth GStreamer support               
i   bluez-hcidump                   - Analyses Bluetooth HCI packets            
i   bluez-tools                     - Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices f
i   gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0       - Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth     
i A gnome-bluetooth                 - GNOME Bluetooth tools                     
i   indicator-bluetooth             - System bluetooth indicator.               
i A libbluedevil1                   - Qt wrapper for bluez                      
i   libbluetooth3                   - Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth s
i A libbluetooth3-dbg               - Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth s
i   libgnome-bluetooth11            - GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library   
i   pulseaudio-module-bluetooth     - Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound serv
```

Comment: There might be a problem with your bluetooth device being supported by your kernel version, please edit the question to include `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Please see the output in my new, related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/646110/kubuntu-15-04-bluedevil-installed-and-working-but-bluetooth-icons-missing-from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had caused the issue when I symlinked kcmshell4 to kcmshell5 as a workaround for a bug in another program. I restored kcmshell4, and now when I launch `bluedevil-monolithic`, all of the menu options work.

Bluetooth config is still not showing up in the panel or system settings, but that is a topic for [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646110/kubuntu-15-04-bluedevil-installed-and-working-but-bluetooth-icons-missing-from).